# Display specific block size with PHP

Tags: php, html, css

I have a list of blocks to print in my web page. Data of these blocks are stored in a database like this:

[image: Image 1]

Priority column corresponds to the priority id to print blocks order by ascendant priority id. Size column corresponds to the size of the block (0 or 1), 0 for half width of the page and 1 for full width of the page.

The blocks can be added dynamically, currently the first half width block positions on the left (float: left) and the next block on the right, any problem for the full width blocks.

My problem is when I have 4 half width blocks successive, I have this display:

[image: Image 2]

Here my code:

```
<?php

$i = 1;
foreach (Block::getAll($diagnostic) as $block)
{
    if ($block['size'] == 0)
    {
        $size = 6;

        if (Block::get($diagnostic, $block['priority'] + 1, 'size') == 0 && Block::get($diagnostic, $block['priority'] + 1, 'size') != null)
        {
?>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="cols-<?php echo $size; ?> blocks">
                    <div class="header"><h3>Titre <?php echo Block::get($diagnostic, $block['priority'], 'priority'); ?></h3></div>
                    <div class="body">
                        <p>Texte <?php echo Block::get($diagnostic, $block['priority'], 'priority'); ?></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="cols-<?php echo $size; ?> blocks">
                    <div class="header"><h3>Titre <?php echo Block::get($diagnostic, $block['priority'] + 1, 'priority'); ?></h3></div>
                    <div class="body">
                        <p>Texte <?php echo Block::get($diagnostic, $block['priority'] + 1, 'priority'); ?></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
<?php
        }
        else if (Block::get($diagnostic, $block['priority'] + 1, 'size') != 0 && Block::get($diagnostic, $block['priority'] - 1, 'size') != 0)
        {
?>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="cols-<?php echo $size; ?> blocks">
                    <div class="header"><h3>Titre <?php echo $block['priority']; ?></h3></div>
                    <div class="body">
                        <p>Texte <?php echo $block['priority']; ?></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
<?php
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $size = 12;
?>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="cols-<?php echo $size; ?> blocks">
                <div class="header"><h3>Titre <?php echo $block['priority']; ?></h3></div>
                <div class="body">
                    <p>Texte <?php echo $block['priority']; ?></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php
    }
++$i;
}
```

In pleasure to read you.

Comment: First, without the code for the Block abstract you're using, we can only really guess that everything is working as you expect it to from there. Second, so that I understand: the screen shot you posted, is that not the arrangement you want with 4 consecutive half-width boxes? What would happen if you had say 3 half-width boxes and then 1 full-width, followed by 2 half-width?

Comment: You're running a `foreach` loop which steps through your elements one at a time, but you display the current and current +1. On the next iteration you've skipped forward only __one__ element, so you display it again. You need to skip forward two elements

Comment: Thank you, but how Can I fix it ?

Comment: I'll ask again, with 4 half-width boxes, what would you expect to happen? It seems as if they are doing exactly what a "half-width" box should do, to me at least. Edit: Also, check your CSS declarations for `cols-0` and `cols-1` to make sure that the full-sized blocks have a `clear:both` property, if they are supposed to behave how I think they are.

Comment: It should be like that:

Titre 9 Titre 10\n
Texte 9 Texte 10

Titre 11 Titre 12\n
Texte 11 Texte 11

Comment: My `row:after` class have a `clear:both`

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

I deleted the container and I added display-block attribute to my blocks with 50% width for half blocks and 100% width for full blocks.

PHP side, I get the size value from the database and I push the half class or full class according this data.